# Pointer modification

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

How to go to a location with pointer addition and change the pointer at that position to point to a new address?
The following code is just an example, I do not want an easy way as just do `ptr[1] = (new addr)`
 but to change the address with the following method:

1. create a new pointer variable `change_ptr`
2. go to designated address with pointer addition
3. change the pointer on that address to point to new address

```
int *ptr[5]; 
void *change_addr = ptr[0];
void *p = change_ptr + sizeof(int*);  
*p = (void*)(uintptr_t)(new address);
```

Comment: "I do not want an easy way". Enjoy your suffering but bear in mind that `&(ptr[0]) + sizeof(int*);` is probably not what you want. If you are looking for the address of the first (next after zeroth) element of   the `ptr` array, you need `&(ptr[0]) + 1`  or `&(ptr[1])` or just `ptr+1`. No `sizeof` of anything anywhere. Also, you cannot dereference a `void*` so `void *p = ...; *p ...` is invalid

Comment: Why isn't `p` an `int*` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out i just need to just `void **` and dereference it to change address

```
int *ptr[5]; 
void *change_addr = ptr[0];
void **p = (void**)( change_ptr + sizeof(int*) );  
*p = (void*)(uintptr_t)(new address);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int *ptr[5]; 
    void *p = &(ptr[1]);  
    &p = (void*)(uintptr_t)(new address);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: nope. int *ptr[5] was just an example. The situation is you don't know what the type or how many there are. You only know the starting pointer, a void*. And then use that void * to do addition to go to, anywhere in that buffer, and change the pointer value

Comment: ptr is the array of pointer. It store the address of other pointer types which will point to. Therefore, it doesn't matter about the types of the pointer when you just want to change the address.

Answer (score 0):

Void-pointers are a great way to shoot yourself in the foot, since the compiler won't be able to do much error-checking for you, but if you insist on using them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   void * ptrs[5] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
   void **p = ptrs+1;
   *p = (void*)((uintptr_t)(0x666));

   for (int i=0; i<5; i++) printf("  ptrs[%i] is %p\n", i, ptrs[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

Running the above program yields this output:

```
ptrs[0] is 0x0
ptrs[1] is 0x666
ptrs[2] is 0x0
ptrs[3] is 0x0
ptrs[4] is 0x0
```

Comment: I just edited my question. `void *ptrs[5]` is just a buffer example. The situation is that I'm only given a void * and I want to do addition with bytes instead of a sizeof(void*) to go to that position and change pointer to point to another address

Comment: If your pointer is a `void *` but you know (somehow) that it is pointing to an array of pointers, then casting your `void *` to `void **` is a reasonable thing to do.  (You don't need to know any further type-information about the pointers since you can assume that all pointer-types are the same size on a given system).  OTOH if your `void *` pointer is pointing to something else, then you would need to know what sort of thing it is pointing to before you can meaningfully calculate a valid offset into the data.

Answer (score 0):

This version is probably overkill...

```
int main() {
    union {
        void *p;
        unsigned long x;
    } foo;

    int a = 5;
    int b = 42;

    int *arr[] = { &a, &b };

    printf( "Before %d\n", *arr[1] );

    foo.p = &arr[0];
    foo.x += sizeof(int*);

    printf( "Still %d\n", *(*((int**)foo.p )) );

    *(*((int**)foo.p )) = 27;

    printf( "After %d\n", *arr[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Before 42
Still 42
After 27
```